# Adding low variables entries to search results

Tags: search, low-variables

How can I search Low Variables content using the Search tag, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Global variables (which LV are, essentially) aren't searchable by the native Search module, nor by any 3rd party search add-on that I know of.

Comment: thank you for the reply, what about via a query?

Comment: Using the Query module could work, but since it uses user data (keywords), it can have security issues. A custom plugin might be better. You'd have separate lists of entries and vars, tho.